# SignalR-rc2 No IConnectionIdPrefixGenerator support any more

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

as of signalr-rc2, IConnectionIdPrefixGenerator is not supported?o 
if so, any plan to expose it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, we own the connection id. If you want extra data you need to use the query string.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. Can I ask one more question? 

is there any good way to get client-specific information when OnDisconnected is invoked? Here's the story. When IConnectionIdPrefixGenerator was available, a combination of SessionId, UserId and Guid was made for a connection Id. A good thing of this approach is that when OnDisconnected() is called, I can easily extract session and user ids (I assume that cookies are not available when OnDisconnected is called)

Is there any good way to handle this case without IConnectionIdPrefixGenerator?

Comment: Do you need to do it from the server side?

Comment: There's no way to do that today. We'll consider adding something in the future.

Comment: Can you guess when that will happen?

Comment: David, what's the reason for removing this in RC2? Soleiljy you can always save a dictionary in db or singleton with the userId and his connections (this way on the disconnect event you can always get the user id by his connection id)